# Pokemon Go google Id account

Tags: pokemon-go

I recently just tried getting back into Pokemon go, but my account was having trouble loading back in. Soon as I re downloaded the app to try to make it work, the login with google button was gone. I'm 17 but it doesn't show up anymore. I have an iphone but why does it not show up?? Answers please

Answer (score 0):

You probably set an incorrect birthday when starting the app for the first time. If the app thinks you're too young to have a google account the option will disappear.
On iOS there's no function to easily clear the cache like on Android, though. You'll either need a cleaner app or reinstall Pokèmon Go.